# String Indices Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I am beginner of Swift 3 and came across one example to retrieve a character using string indices. I do not have swift 3 installed but I doubt one thing that is different from explanation. I do not know, it is bug, writing mistake or what. Below is a example from page 166 of "The Swift Programming Language(Swift 3 beta)".

```
let greeting = "Guten Tag!"

greeting[greeting.startIndex] //Prints G according to text. Fine according to definition.

greeting[greeting.index(before:greeting.endIndex)] //Prints ! according to text. Now if you look at greeting String, the character before endIndex is g. It must print g according to definition.

greeting[greeting.index(after:greeting.startIndex)] //Prints u according to text and is right according to definition also.
```

Somebody can explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) in section "String Indices":

> The endIndex property is the position **after** the last character in a String. As a result, the endIndex property isn’t a valid argument to a string’s subscript.

This means that `endIndex` is actually quite like the length of the string and the last character is at index `endIndex - 1`.

So the output is correct. Also, the same "Guten Tag!" example is given on that documentation page.

Comment: I will, after 7 minutes. :)